# MariaDB: Role not applicable after creation

Tags: mariadb, roles

I' creating a role in MariaDB by a user that has Global Privileges:

[image: user with global privileges]

```
CREATE ROLE role_test
```

After creation the role is visible in the "Roles Mapping":

```
SELECT * from mysql.roles_mapping;
```

But it's NOT visible in the "Applicable Roles":

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.APPLICABLE_ROLES;
```

And it's not possible to grant the Role to a user.

But if I create the Role with user "root@localhost" who has Global Privileges too, then the Role immediately appears in the "Applicable Roles":

[image: role added by root user]

Even if I grant the role to the user that should grant it to another user and do it  WITH ADMIN OPTION it's not possible:

```
GRANT role_msc_cus TO 'msc_dev'@localhost;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'msc_dev'@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'xxx';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
GRANT role_msc_cus TO 'x2@x2.com'@'localhost' WITH ADMIN OPTION
```

=> "Access denied for user 'msc_dev'@'localhost'

Answer (score 3):

There is a bit of missing information in your question to exactly pin point the problem, but I will try my best to explain what's going on and hopefully you find where it went wrong.

1. When selecting from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.applicable_roles`, you're getting the list of roles that can be activated (with `SET ROLE`) by the current logged-in user. So the contents will differ based on which user you are logged in as.
2. It doesn't matter what global privileges the user has when selecting from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.applicable_roles`. What matters is what's in `mysql.role_mappings`. If a role is granted to the user, it will show up in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.applicable_roles` **when** querying `applicable_roles` as that user.
3. When a role is created, that role is automatically granted to the role that created it and that user can grant the newly created role to other users or roles. So if you created the role with `root@localhost`, when you query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.applicable_roles` logged in as `root@localhost`, you'll see the role there and you'll see that `IS_GRANTABLE` is set to `YES`.

Being able to `GRANT` a role to a user is controlled by the `WITH_ADMIN` flag in `mysql.role_mappings`.

For user `A@%` to be able to grant role R1 to any other user, user A must have had role R1 granted like so:

```sql
GRANT R1 TO A WITH ADMIN OPTION;
```

Without `WITH ADMIN OPTION`, `A@%` can only activate the role for himself, not grant it to others.

Comment: "WITH ADMIN OPTION" doesn't work in my case. The Solution for me was to create the role with the same account that grants the role to another user.